# bash_aliases doesn't work

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

I created the file `~/.bash_aliases` within these lines:

```
# my alias here

eclipse="eclipse</dev/null &>/dev/null &"
okular="okular</dev/null &>/dev/null &"
libre="libreoffice</dev/null &>/dev/null &"
```

My `~/.bashrc` is ready to find aliases:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I then executed `. ~/.basharc` and also `source .bashrc` but aliases I created still don't work.

Comment: Maybe because you are missing the `alias` in front of each line. What you are defining now is variables, not aliases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined *plain variables*, not *aliases*.

The alias definitions in `bash` must start with the keyword `alias`, so make the definitions as:

```
alias eclipse="eclipse </dev/null &>/dev/null &"
alias okular="okular </dev/null &>/dev/null &"
alias libre="libreoffice </dev/null &>/dev/null &"
```

Comment: Yes, sorry but I founded an example onile that omitted `alias` for some reason and I replicated it without thinking. It's clear now.

Comment: @Glk-78 Now you've found a very good reason to avoid random technical articles on the internet.

Comment: True, but I also paid few attention. Maybe at the lines above there was somekind of explenation I didn't see.